# How to access windows cmd messages through Python

Tags: python, cmd

I have this code in Python which runs perfectly well. What it does is it deletes files from a list on a filesheet. Now my question is if the cmd returns file not found could not delete how can I make Python aware of it so that I could put in a log the files I haven't deleted? I thought error handling would help but it wasn't an error in part of Python since I was just invoking the cmd through Python. Any ideas are welcome. :)

Example of how I invoke the cmd:

```
import os
os.system('CLS()')
```

Comment: How is the Python script invoking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

"The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, **and obtain their return codes**."

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are the codes I was used and work well in Windows environment:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["cmd"])
```

It's also available to accept more parameters as list in Python
And it also could invoke your *.exe app to execute.